# Trying to remove hyphens from a string in C

Tags: c

I am solving a problem in which I have a date (YYYY-MM-DD) as user input and I need to find out the day(Sunday, Monday,.. ). I have tried to remove the hyphen so that I can proceed with Zellor's rule. To achieve that I used a loop. However, it doesn't seem to work.
Here's is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char date[11], datenum[9]; 
    int date_num;
    printf("Enter the date in yyyy-mm-dd format\n");
    scanf("%s", &date);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        if (date[i]!='-' && j<8){
            datenum[j] = date[i];

            j++;
        }
    } 
    printf("%s\n", datenum);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting 20210609 as output when I gave 2021-06-09 as input but that doesn't seem to be the case. Instead, I got 202106092021-06-09.

Comment: `date` isn't big enough, you didn't leave room for the null terminator.

Comment: You also didn't leave room for the null terminator in `datenum`, and didn't add one at the end.

Comment: Have you completely forgotten that strings in C end with a `\0` character?

Comment: You can use `strtok()` to split the input at `-` characters instead of your own loop.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit it. However, the problem doesn't seem to be that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working too hard.  Rather than copying data into one buffer and then moving it around, just write things to the right place.  Something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
        char datenum[9];

        printf("Enter the date in yyyy-mm-dd format\n");
        if( 3 != scanf("%4s-%2s-%2s", datenum, datenum + 4, datenum + 6) ){
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                return 1;
        }
        printf("%s\n", datenum);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would definitely follow this one. However, can you see how I went wrong in my code?

Comment: As mentioned in several comments, you failed to terminate the string.  The `printf` inside the loop prints the initial `20210609`, and the `printf` outside the loops prints that data again, followed by whatever random garbage is in memory after `datenum` (this behavior is undefined, but based on the output this appears to be what's happening).  It seems that your platform has placed `date` in memory after `datenum`, so you're seeing a few bytes of random garbage followed by `date`.

Comment: About the inside printf statement, I was just trying to debug and forgot to remove it before posting here. The excess 2021-06-09 was what I was worried about. Thank you for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 1):

A lot to fix in the code, but literally solving your problem statement that the content printed on console is not what you expect.

You are expecting `20210609` to be printed. But you are getting `2021060920210609█2021-06-09`

```
printf("%c", datenum[j]);
```

prints a character from `datenum` in a loop.

And then, there is a `printf("%s\n", datenum);` which is going to append a string contained by `datenum`. Get rid of the `printf()` after the loop and notice that the `printf()` in the loop is doing what is expected. However, note that the contents of `datenum` aren't what you printed in the loop. So, you still have something to fix.

Think over the fact that `printf("%s\n", datenum);` is able to print more than what `datenum` can accommodate. There has to be something wrong. With strings, it is usually the missing `'\0'`.

**Hint:** Did you forget to add a `'\0'` after populating `datenum`?

To solve it entirely, without optimizing your design, remove the `printf()` in the loop and add a `datenum[8] = '\0';` before calling the `print()` to print it as a string using `%s`.

Try it out: https://onlinegdb.com/y3GuLj1GG

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me. I was using the inside loop to check where I was going wrong but forgot to remove it before posting here. I have edited it now. Gracias!

Comment: @Akil: You can/should mark the answer as 'accepted' if it solved your problem, and/or at least nudged you in the correct direction.